# SASS/Compass: Reference Instead of Include

Tags: html, css, web, compass-sass, bootstrap-sass

I'm currently working on a large business website using Compass (the Bootstrap Fork). We are using many different scss files, all of them including base.scss, where our variables and mixins live. Now, we want to compile some optional css files from our scss files, that receive the variables from the base.scss files at compile time, but won't have the overhead of all the other rules defined in base included in the finished and compiled css file.
So basically, I'm looking for a way to reference the base file instead of including it. I just want $companyColor (etc...) to be replaced with the value of the corresponding variable in the base file.

**Please note**, that I cannot have those lose files @imported in my base file, because these files overwrite some of the base rules and are only loaded on certain pages of the website to provide an alternate theme.

Is this at all possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understood what you asked.

But if you want some variables from `base.scss` to be included in other scss files, you can split your `base.scss` in two files:

- `shared-vars.scss` containing variables that will be included in
  optional scss files
- `base.scss` containg all other variables and mixins, **and importing**
  `shared-vars.scss`

Now you can import `base.scss` in your main scss files and only import `shared-vars.scss` in your optional scss files

Comment: I've always liked the practise of keeping all the variables in their own file, separate form any mixins.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. I wasn't hoping for this answer, but already expected it. This was sort of a last resort approach, since I'd hoped that there was a simpler (as in _"I won't have to do the tedious copy / paste work"_) way to achieve this. But I guess I'll have to do just that... (Thinking of making my apprentice do that, actually... ;-) )

Thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: @Dre, I agree. But in some cases, you can't have only one variables.scss. @armin use this *copy/paste time* to also create a mixins.scss with all mixins, it's always better for maintenance. And don't forget to accept my answer `;)`